# Typescript OR types

Tags: typescript

I have a variable which can be either of `Array<{name:"string"}>` or `string`.

I attempted this:

```
let nameObj:Array<{name:"string"}> | string;
```

But when I do `nameObj[0].name`, the compiler gives error saying:`"Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string "`

How do I do this then?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? let nameObj: { name: string }[] | string;

Comment: @JimmyHöglund I still have that error

Answer (score 3):

Type `Array<{name: string;}> | string` make TypeScript compiler not sure whether the variable is `Array<{name: string;}` or `string`. It is not safe in runtime. You have to specify the output for each case, or specify one type if you know that the variable always is `string` or `Array<{name: string;}`

```js
let nameObj: Array<{ name: string; }> | string;

const name: string = typeof nameObj === "string" 
   ? nameObj : nameObj[0].name;
```

```js
let nameObj: Array<{ name: string; }> | string;
// you are sure this variable is Array
const name = (Array<{ name: string; }> nameObj)[0].name;
```

However your code `nameObj.name` is wrong. nameObj is Array, Object. You have to add index reference such as `nameObj[0].name`